# How to close connection to Realm

Tags: javascript, node.js, realm, dbconnection

I can't close realm's connection. I call **realm.close()**, but nodejs process is still locked.

Here is source code:

```
import Realm from 'realm';

class App {
  static main = async () => {
     const realm = await Realm.open({ path: 'db.realm', schema: [ MODELS ] });
     realm.close();
  }
}

App.main();
```

Comment: You might just need to add like 500ms delay or something.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce after something what?

Comment: After opening and before closing

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1387